# String.format() for string and numbers in Java

Tags: java, android, format, string.format

I will prepare String for use substring function and i need to have always 4 characters. In stackoverflow I found code like this but it is works only for numbers.

```
writeHead = String.format("%04d", writeHead);
```

But in my case i need to do this same for text + numbers.
12a --> 012a

```
String head = "12a"; 
String writeHead = String.format("%04d", head);//doesnt work
//need 012a as String
```

Comment: Do you need leading Zero all time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.format is not good if yor text/number pattern is fixed (i.e. all your numbers ends with letter a?).
A quick and dirty left padding with zeroes:

```
String head="12a";    
String writeHead = "0000"+head;
writeHead=writeHead.substring(writeHead.length()-4);
```

Comment: Thanks, i should hit on this idea by myself

Answer (score 0):

a simple thing like this will do

```
String head = "12a";
while(head.length < 4){
    head += "0"+head;
}
```

just check the length and append

Answer (score 0):

```
int head = 12;
String writeheader = String.format("0%da", head);
```

or

String header = 12a;
String writeHeader = String.format("0%s", head);